# how to show that $n^k x^n$ is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

It seems to be clear that sequence of functions $f_n (x)=n^k x^n$ on (0,1) is convergent where $k$ is a fixed natural number

But I can't show it.

I tried to show that by differentiation, but it didn't work well for me.

$f'_n (x)=n^{k+1} x^{n-1}$ and $f''_n (x)=n^{k+1} (n-1)x^{n-2}$.

How to show it?

Comment: ... What about $x=1$?

Comment: It's convergent on $[0,1)$, not $[0,1]$. (I'm assuming $k$ is fixed, $x\in[0,1)$, and $n$ is the index variable for the sequence.

Comment: It's all my fault. I meant that (0,1)...

Comment: Can you do it when $x=1/2?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking logarithms, $\log f_n(x) = -cn + k\log n$ where $c=|\log x|$. It should now be easy to show (by calculus, for example) that $\log f_n(x)\to-\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, so that $f_n(x)\to0$.